# EF Core 3.1 One to One Relation, Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am trying here to convert one of my old projects written in Java, Hibernate to ASP.NET Core 3, EF Core 3.1

What I am trying to do, is, map the Advertisment class, with an abstract class and it's derived parts using One to One ralationship and TPH strategy. Mapping the object hierarchy with the TPH worked fine, but the relationship between it and Advertisment class causes some problems, mainly, when I try to access that one item of the advertise.

***Error Message***

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

    AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml

     <h1>@Model.Id  @(((AutoItem)(Model.Item)).AdvertismentId)</h1>

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
```

Here is the relevant code:

***Abstract base class***

```
[Table("items")]
    public abstract class ItemCategory
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double? Price { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string? Brand { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(500,ErrorMessage =" Description can contain maximum 500 characters")]
        [MinLength(20, ErrorMessage = " Description must contain maximum 20 characters")]
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int AdvertismentId { get; set; }
        public Advertisment Advertisment { get; set; } 
    }
```

***Concrete Part***

```
[Table("items")]
    public class AutoItem : ItemCategory
    {
        [Display(Name="Production year")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? ProductAge { get; set; }

        public int? Mileage { get; set; }
    }
```

***Advertisment class***

```
 [Table("advertisments")]
    public class Advertisment
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }

        public string? Picture { get; set; }

        public ItemCategory Item { get; set; }
    }
```

***Configuration in the DbContext class***

```
        public DbSet<ItemCategory> Items { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AutoItem> AutoItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Advertisment> advertisments { get; set;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Define the TPH using Fluent.API
            modelBuilder.Entity<ItemCategory>()
                .ToTable("items")
                .HasDiscriminator<string>("item_type")
                .HasValue<AutoItem>("auto_type");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Advertisment>()
                .ToTable("advertisments");

            // One - to - One relationship between ItemCategory <-> Advertisment
            modelBuilder.Entity<Advertisment>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Item)
                .WithOne(a => a.Advertisment)
                .HasForeignKey<ItemCategory>(ic => ic.AdvertismentId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        }
```

***Action Method***

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            // fetches the data using context.class.FindAsync()
            var ad = await advertismentRepository.GetAdvertisment(1);

            return View(ad);
        }
```

***Razor View - the problem comes here when I try the acces the Item of this advertise***

```
@model Advertisment
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
 <h1>@Model.Id  @(((AutoItem)(Model.Item)).AdvertismentId)</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show your `GetAdvertisment` ?

Comment: @XingZou This is what it is right now. I assumed related entities are loaded automaticaly like in Java ->>>


 public async Task<Advertisment> GetAdvertisment(int Id)
        {
            return await context.advertisments.FindAsync(Id);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that `Model.Item` is probably null. Try to [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) in your repository `GetAdvertisment` method using `Include` like

```
public async Task<T> GetAdvertisment(int id)
{
    return await _context.advertisments
                         .Include(a => a.Item)                         
                         .SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
}
```